# how to convert es6 codes into code that IE can rendered

Tags: laravel, npm

i am currently working on project that contains a lot of ES codes.when i run the project on IE it shows that there are lots of errors does not support in IE. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why you add `laravel` in tags? It's `javascript` question. But nvm, up to you.

The solution is you should use javascript polyfill. So, the ES code can be converted to the code that browser understand. Since you're using Laravel, you can use `Laravel Mix` to transpile your code.

Answer (score 0):

use polyfill.js in your script

```js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-polyfills/0.1.42/polyfill.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Use polyfill to make it compatible with IE

npm install react-app-polyfill

check more on this link 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill